# why session have session id after session timeout in jsp?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, struts

Hi in jsp of JavaScript i am checking userdId  in session or not it always have session id if   session expires also, but i checked in java Action class after session expires userid is   null but not in jsp. [code link](http://jsfiddle.net/hari034/xWtPz/)

Comment: Please try and rephrase your question to be clearer.  I don't actually understand what your problem is other than something is wrong with you sessions somewhere...

Comment: hi Endopage, after session expires i have to redirect the page to login.jsp but at present it displaying login.jsp of same page DIV place..total page not redirecting

Comment: Generally it should not happend but check with `session.isNew()`

Answer (score 0):

Try alerting the sessionId in your javascript code. You will find that the sessionId is different after the old one has expired.

Also check what the code is doing when a new session is created. It might be setting the userid in the new session.